# Writing a String to a text file after a certain string Java

Tags: java, file

So I'm writing to a text file and I was wondering if there was a way to write underneath a certain string after writing to the file before. So say I wrote

Label1

Label2

Label3

Is there a way to write to the file on the line after Label1 after writing all the labels without specifically knowing what line it is?

Comment: No, this is something you have to implement by yourself.

Comment: Use a [RandomAccesFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to find the label, then read ahead to the end of the line, then write your new stuff after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the file with the line you added and replace the original if successful.

A file is just like an array of bytes which you can grow at the end.  You can't insert or delete bytes from a file. All you can do is shift them around.